# How to find out if a UI element is fully visible inside a Scroll View with TestPlanesAABB

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a Scroll View in Unity 3D. I Want buttons only to be clickable when they are fully visible on the screen (not just a small part of them showing on the edge), so, after doing some research, I'm trying to write a test function with this:

```
private bool isFullyVisible(GameObject obj) {

    var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(Camera.main);
    var image = GetComponent<Image>();
    var bounds = new Bounds(image.transform.localPosition,image.rectTransform.rect.size);

    return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, bounds);


}
```

Unfortunately, this function return all objects on the screen as fully visible, even though some of them have just a small part showing. What is wrong and how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "problem" here is that `TestPlanesAABB()` returns true if *any part* of the passed collider is inside the volume.

You can think of this test as being "do these two colliders *intersect*?" where the `Planes[]` array represents the surfaces of a (heavily distorted) cube.

In order to fix this you would need to inset the `Planes[]` by an amount equal to the size of the button.  This may or may not be easy to accomplish.

Alternatively, you could use a point-sized collider for the button and test if the center is visible (and just accept that buttons would be clickable if *at least half* of their face is visible).  Or you could *test all four corners* in this manner and only allow the button to be clicked if all four are visible (actually, you could short-cut and allow it as long as 3 are: the fourth *must* be visible if it is axis aligned and 3 corners pass).

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s . I like your solution of testing 3 corners, but I'm a bit concerned for use in cases wherer you need to check at every frame (i.e: on update()).. where you would need to check when the element has fully entered the screen. Would it hurt performance too badly? Do you think of a better solution to this case?

Comment: @raphadko If you're doing it on Update, then get the `Planes[]` from the camera once and pass it to each button's `isFullyVisible()` method. That will cut down on the processing each frame.  But total CPU use shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I did a follow up question about this, if you could help out I would greatly appreciate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123186/find-out-an-objects-box-actual-4-edges-scaled-to-the-screen-camera-size-unity