# Find out an object's box actual 4 edges scaled to the screen/camera size (Unity 2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm writing a function to figure out if a 2D object is completely inside another.
I'm doing this by getting the object's position, then with this position and it's size, calculating the object's edges position, then doing a check with Camera.main.pixelRect.Contains. This is my current code:

```
 // get the center of the object
 Vector2 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(card.transform.position);

 // get the bounding box
 var rect = image.transform.rect;

 var topLeft = new Vector2(pos.x - (rect.width / 2), pos.y - (rect.height / 2);


return Camera.main.pixelRect.Contains(topLeft);
```

My problem is, being new to Unity, the measurements do not match. I'm confused on when the object is scaled with the screen size, I will get the actual width of the image and it calculates wrong.

I also tested getting rect with:

```
rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;
```

Can someone help me out how to make this work?

Ps: if there is a better way of checking when a 2D object is completely inside another, I would also accept that.

Comment: [Rect#Overlap](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.Overlaps.html) will return if the two rectangles touch. [Rect#Contains](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.Contains.html) will return if a point is inside the rectangle. As for the scalar, always convert points to screenspace or never do. Don't mix and match. If the transform hierarchies are all weirdly scaled, then converting is probably best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Draco18s pointed out, you convert `pos` to screenspace but not `rect`.

If you look at unity's API docs for `WorldToScreenPoint()`
it says that it

> Transforms position from world space into screen space. Screenspace is
>   defined in pixels.

whereas `transform.position` returns

> The position of the transform in world space.

What you have is a problem of combining screenspace, measured in pixels, and world space, which is totally different.

Because you are using `pixelRect`, I would recommend changing `var rect = image.transform.rect;`
to be `var rect = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(image.transform.position);`

You will then of course have to also check the other corners in a similar way, and if all 4 corners return true then the the object is inside the other.